# Library installation using compiler

Tags: c++, rcpp, armadillo

I have been writing C++ code snippets sporadically to speed things up in R via Rcpp, but now I would like to do more using Armadillo library, but I am having trouble installing it.

The README file instructs to create a location for "include" folder and `tell your compiler to use that location for header files  (in addition to the locations it uses already).`

If I save the "include" folder into C:\Users\me\Documents\ARMADILLO, then how do I instruct the compiler to use the appropriate location?

After some search, I tries typing into command line the following (after prompt: `C:\Users\me>`):
`g++ Documents\ARMADILLO\include`, but it did not work ("permission denied"). I hence wonder how this should be done.

Moreover, the README file finally instructs to:  `Configure your compiler to link with LAPACK and BLAS` - I would very much appreciate an advice how this should be done as well.

Thanks a lot!

PS: I have Windows 7 and VS Express 2013 for Desktop.

Comment: To use Armadillo with R, install the [RcppArmadillo](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.armadillo.html) package (directly using the R command line).

Comment: If you're asked to use g++, on windows it means MinGW. There are several places where you could get mingw, one being http://nuwen.net/mingw.html, another http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/download.php

Comment: Both comments are correct and relevant; the accepted answer is not. Read up on Rcpp and maybe the Rcpp-FAQ.

Comment: Thanks, I am already running C++ Armadillo via RcppArmadillo :-)

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio uses *solutions* which are containers of *projects*. Each project has a settings page (right click the project in the Solution Explorer window). Under "Configuration properties" there's a VC++ Directories page, which in turn lists "Include Directories". Append `;C:\Users\me\Documents\ARMADILLO`

BTW, I find it useful to put such libs under `C:\libs\`. Saves on path length.

Comment: This answer is not applicable / correct in the context of the question: Rcpp.

Comment: The first few pages of Rcpp.org don't state compiler requirements, and this answer is applicable for the most common compiler on Windows (also the one mentioned in the question).

Comment: Please read the [Rcpp-FAQ](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-FAQ.pdf).  We can't cram eight different vignettes into an opening paragraph.